# Safecracker Registration: how to edit Channel entry after registration?

Tags: channel-entries, members, safecracker, safecracker-registration

After a member is registered via [Safecracker Registration](https://objectivehtml.com/safecracker-registration), how do I allow the member to update his/her Channel entry?

Safecracker Registration has the option `edit_member="yes"`, so I created a Safecracker form with the fields I want members to be able to update. The opening tag is something like this:

```
{exp:safecracker channel="members" class="form-horizontal" edit_member="yes" error_handling="inline" id="profile_manager_about_me" include_jquery="no" return="/profile-manager/" safecracker_head="no"}
```

While the member is logged in and submits the Safecracker form, a field error is returned stating that the `email` field is required (it's not one of the fields to be edited).

Is Safecracker Registration's `edit_member="yes"` only supposed to be used when you are also editing member data along with possibly the Channel entry data? How can I edit just the Channel entry data?

Could I use the global variable `member_id` to get the current member's entry in the Channel, then get that result's `entry_id` (there should only be one, I think), then use the `entry_id` as a parameter in the Safecracker tag pair? Seems convoluted?

Comment: You mention channel entry: are you using an add-on like Zoo Visitor or Profile:Edit as well?

Comment: Yes. It's called "Safecracker Registration."

Comment: Do you mean to complete their profile? Are they not doing so during the registration process— submitting the other fields of data?

Comment: No. The registration only accepts the email address + password + confirm password + a couple of Channel fields. There are more fields than what I expose during the registration process.

Comment: @Tyssen It's my add-on Safecracker Registration. It's the same concept as those add-ons, but a little more basic. I use it on all my client sites and is all I ever need with how I build sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `edit_member="yes"` parameter in conjunction with using the member fields from your registration form. If you don't want those fields, just make this a standard safecracker form and edit your profile entry as normal.

There are several ways you can do it, but my advise would to use hidden form fields to store the values you don't want to be visible. This way, you don't have to workaround any unforeseen limitations you may come across.

Comment: So, say there is a hidden field "email" with the current member's email address, then it's OK? What about using the current member's member_id to get the related Channel entry, then just using a standard Safecracker form for that? I'm just reluctant about the hidden field approach.

Comment: Wait - what do you mean by "member fields?" I've decided to only use the bare minimum EE member fields (email, password, password_confirm). Everything else was put in a Channel field. I want to edit the data stored in the Channel associated with the member.

Comment: Right, the member fields include the email, password, and password_confirm fields. You can use the screen_name and username fields as well, but those are optional and default to the email if that don't exists.  I typically include the email and password fields when users are updating their profile. However, if you want to prevent users from updating them, just include them as hidden fields.

Comment: I haven't had the time to explore these options. Will do soon. Quick question about the hidden field approach: if I were to manipulate the DOM and replace the email address with another member's, would I be modifying his/her Channel entry when I submit the form?

Comment: TBH I am not sure what would happen, that's probably a good thing to test. I don't usually have to go that degree of security and just use hidden fields because the problem has never come up. Normally I just leave the field visible and it can be changed at will, so I don't see how making it hidden would be any less secure.

Comment: Finally got to this problem again. I tried the hidden `email` field approach. It works. Then I manipulated the DOM to change the email address to `a@a.com`. It updated the current member's email address (it was used as the author of the entry, I saw the email address in the Members section, etc.). I manipulated the DOM again, using another member's email address. It did the same thing: updated the current member's email address to hacked email. It means that I had 2 members with the same email address. I'm not comfortable with this approach.

Comment: From my original post: "Could I use the global variable member_id to get the current member's entry in the Channel, then get that result's entry_id (there should only be one, I think), then use the entry_id as a parameter in the Safecracker tag pair? Seems convoluted?"

Comment: I see what you mean. I have a new add-on designed to make stuff like that easier. It's called Entries and is designed to pull data from Channel Entries is a wide variety of ways. https://objectivehtml.com/entries This add-on is still a work in progress though.

Answer (score 1):

In fact I think that the e-mail address field is required, but you can hide it in a hidden field.

Comment: Perhaps. It makes sense to be required on registration. Maybe not so much when editing? Hidden field seems prone to possible hacking. Would probably be better to figure out the entry_id by using the member_id somehow? Just seems convoluted.

Comment: You don't have to use it or make it a hidden field, but this would make your form a regular Safecracker tag and nothing to do with the registration components. When you use `edit_member` you are editing a profile, to which the email and password fields belong. I use hidden fields all the time, and sometimes are the easiest way to solve the problem. Nothing wrong with it on a technical level IMO.